# Kubernetes nginx-ingress TLS issue

Tags: ssl, nginx, kubernetes

My company has an existing CA certificate for *fake.example.com* and an A record that maps *fake.example.com* to the IP of our load balancer

The load balancer is forwarding traffic to our Kubernetes cluster.

In the cluster, I've deployed the nginx-ingress helm chart, exposing NodePort for https at 30200

I've created a k8s TLS secret named *test-secret* from the above certificate.

I've deployed an app with service 'test' and have installed the following ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - fake.example.com
    secretName: test-secret
  rules:
    - host: fake.example.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /myapp
          backend:
            serviceName: test
            servicePort: 8080
```

So, if i execute

```
curl https://{ip for k8s node}:30200/myapp/ping -H 'Host:fake.example.com' -k --verbose
```

I get the expected response from my app, but I also see

```
* Server certificate:
*  subject: O=Acme Co; CN=Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate
*  start date: Jan 25 20:52:16 2018 GMT
*  expire date: Jan 25 20:52:16 2019 GMT
*  issuer: O=Acme Co; CN=Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate
```

I've confirmed in the nginx.conf file that for *server_name fake.exampe.com* the *ssl_certificate*, *ssl_certificate_key* , and *ssl_trusted_certificate* are pointing the the correct location

So my question is, is it possible to configure nginx to use the correct certificate in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a secret named `test-secret`.

```
➜  charts git:(master) kubectl describe secret --namespace operation mydomain.cn-cert
Name:         mydomain.cn-cert
Namespace:    operation
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  Opaque

Data
====
tls.crt:  3968 bytes
tls.key:  1678 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

The ingress controller will default to `Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate` when no certificate is available (which you say is in `test-secret`), the certificate is invalid, or if the controller can't find a matching host in `.spec.tls[]`, or you hit the default-backend without a default TLS cert configured.

Since you are able to reach your service, then I suspect that either:

1. Your `test-secret` is invalid, maybe because you are missing an intermediate, or CA certificate
2. Your `test-secret` is in the wrong namespace
3. The tls secret is not being matched, (maybe because of using `https://{ip for k8s node}:30200/myapp/ping -H 'Host:fake.example.com'` or the `-k` flag?)

It's unusual to expose your ingress controller as `NodePort` when you have a load balancer in front of it. If this is a cloud deployment, then you would use type `LoadBalancer`. If this is on premise, you might look at [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/)